# the best implementation of RFC 2104 HMAC-SHA1

Tags: php, sha1, hmac

What is the best implementation of RFC 2104 HMAC-SHA1 alg. in php?
I have read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php but when I try them I get
different results.
Thank's

Answer (score 3):

Just use the function you linked.

`hash_hmac("sha1", $message, $key);`

$message and $key are the strings provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

The hash extension is definitely the best option you have in PHP. `hash()` and specifically `hash_hmac()` as you pointed out are both supporting SHA1 and both do a good job of it.